# How to make an element stuck on the corner of the page, without increasing page size?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am creating my wordpress theme, but I've run into a problem. I'm trying to keep my footer stuck on the bottom corner of the page using a margin-top, but what happens is that the size of the page increases. I've set max-width to 100%, so I am not sure of why this happens. However here is the code. Thanks in advance for helping me. 
I'm putting just the code of the footer, it is inside a container div with 100% max-width, the only problem is when the footer increases the height of the page.

```html
 <?php if (is_front_page()) { ?>
  
  <style> 
  .site-footer {
   margin-top: 80%;
  } 
  </style>
  
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Ok so to do so, you need to change the position attribute. 

Try 

    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;

Comment: Wow man! I feel stupid for how simple it was, but thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking but I think you may want to try:

```
.site-footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

or

```
.site-footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow that did the trick! Thank you so much man! Just it seems to have overcome the float: left, so now it's stuck on the right, any idea to solve it?

Comment: No problem. Using absolute or fixed positioning will take it out of the document flow, so floats won't work.  I assume you want it to be full width? if so, add right: 0; left:0;

Answer (score 2):

does your .site-footer have a margin set? that could potentially be pushing the page height. the height of .site-footer would also determine how "tall" the page becomes once it set to a top-margin of 80%. margin-top will also be 80% of whatever the page  height is at the time, not 80% of the browser window

Comment: {position:absolute;bottom:0;} will put it at the very bottom of the content of your page as @Neil below has pointed out. {position:fixed;} will put it at the bottom of your browser window, and will still be visible no matter how "tall" your page content is